# Implementation checking if $K_7$ is a minor of a graph

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, algorithms

Is there a specific implementation checking if the clique on 7 vertices $K_7$ is a minor of a given graph?

SAGE proposes a method but [it's very slow](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/8112/graph-minor-code-too-slow-in-certain-situations-sage-46/). 
There is a linear-time algorithm for checking $K_5$-minor free graphs, is there something for $K_7$? Implemented?

Comment: I would guess that the case of $K_5$ has been specifically worked on and developed and optimised because of its importance compared to basically any other $K_n$. I don't know the algorithm myself, but have you looked into it and tried to generalize it? It may be impossible, but it may also be very easy.